# Share dynamic module in NestJS - what happens when the dynamic module is registered few times?

Tags: nestjs

I need to share a dynamic module. In the documentation I've found that we can share services in the global scope.
Yes, this is a solution. However, I would like to find out if it is possible on the module level. That is why I am interested in ***what happens when the dynamic module is registered few times***. From practice, I see that it creates different instances of modules in NestJS.
The module behaviour is different as it is in Angular however the NestJS likes to mention Angular similarity.
The property module takes me away. Now I understand that it is used only to control the module behavior. However, I do not see any
explanation in the documentation. I saw similar questions. But I've not found details that I am interested in.

The following code is only idea. It has not been checked.

```js
import { DynamicModule, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from './config.service';

@Module({})
export class ConfigModule {
  static register(options: Record<string, any>): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: ConfigModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: 'CONFIG_OPTIONS',
          useValue: options,
        },
        ConfigService,
      ],
      exports: [ConfigService],
    };
  }
}

export const ConfiguredConfigModule = ConfigModule.register({key: 'flower'});
... 

@Module({
  imports: [ConfiguredConfigModule]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NestJS likes to mention Angular similarity.

Similarity, not parity. They are *similar* not the *same*. Differences in behavior are expected

> From practice, I see that it creates different instances of modules in NestJS.

This is correct. By *convention* we use names like `forRoot` when we expect to make something once and re-use it from the root module and `register` when we expect to have to register a module multiple times, but this is onyl community convention and not a hard rule at all. When you call `DynamicModule.forRoot/register/Async()` you **will** create a dynamic module in thecurrent module's context

If you want to share a dynamic module, I would suggest creating a wrapper around the dynamic module, so you have the wrapper call to the `.forRoot()/register()/whaterver()` and export the dynamic module by name (add `exports: [DynamicModule]`. This will allow you to import the wrapper and have one instance of the DynamicModule without having to make it a global instance